# Alternative to negative look ahead

Tags: regex, go, terraform

I am writing a Terraform module where I need to capture and replace tokens in strings. The tokens are enclosed by `{{...}}` but I do not want to capture those that match `{{global-...}}`.

For example:

```
locals {
    input = "Hello {{name}} this is {{global-env}}. Welcome to {{home}}."
    output = replace(local.input, "/{{(.+?)}}/", "{{$1-en_US}}")
}

output "output" { value = local.output }
# Actual:   Hello {{name-en_US}} this is {{global-env-en_US}}. Welcome to {{home-en_US}}
# Expected: Hello {{name-en_US}} this is {{global-env}}. Welcome to {{home-en_US}}
```

In C# Regex, I could have used a negative look ahead:

```
{{(?!global-)(.+?)}}
```

However, since Terraform and its underlying Go lang runtime do not support lookarounds, what is the alternative? Being inside a Terraform module does not allow me to iterate over each match and test the capture group either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around it by using a second replacement to remove `-en_US` from placeholders that start with `global-` and end with `-en_US` after the first replacement:

```
output = replace(replace(local.input, "/{{(.+?)}}/", "{{$1-en_US}}"), "({{global-.+?)-en_US}}", "$1}}")
```